# flutter navigated screen was not built when app lifecycle is paused

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, for scenarios where we need to navigate to another page after a countdown, we can set a timer to navigate after a certain period. However, I found that the page navigation does not occur if the app goes into the background. What would be a good solution for this scenario?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<void> _delayGoSecondScreen() async {
    debugPrint('_delayGoSecondScreen called');
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
    debugPrint('_delayGoSecondScreen start');
    if (mounted) {
      await Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute<void>(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => const SecondsScreen(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _delayGoSecondScreen,
        tooltip: 'Delay Go Next Screen',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SecondsScreen> createState() => _SecondsScreenState();
}

class _SecondsScreenState extends State<SecondsScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    debugPrint('$runtimeType initState');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint('$runtimeType build');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('SecondsScreen'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Expected results:
log shows _SecondsScreenState initState right after _delayGoSecondScreen start

Actual results:
only print _delayGoSecondScreen start,
after turn on the screen and app resumed this log shows_SecondsScreenState initState.

Answer (score 0):

use [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager/install) package

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:workmanager/workmanager.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
  Workmanager().initialize(callbackDispatcher);
}

void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) {
    if (task == "delayed_navigation") {
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
        // Perform the navigation to the next screen here
        // Use the navigator to go to the desired screen
      });
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  void _delayedNavigation() {
    Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(
      "delayed_navigation",
      "delayed_navigation",
      inputData: <String, dynamic>{},
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _delayedNavigation,
        tooltip: 'Delay Go Next Screen',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```